# scala3 extension method type parameter

Tags: scala, extension-methods, dotty, scala-3

this is a direct translation of my scala2 code to scala3

```
trait Narrow[F[_], A, B <: A: ClassTag]:
  def apply(fa: F[A]): F[B]

extension [F[_], A] (fa: F[A]):
  def narrow[B: ClassTag] (using op: Narrow[F, A, B]): F[B] = op(fa)
```

I need to specify the type of the narrow operation at the call site, however extension methods do not allow that syntax. what are there the best workarounds for this limitation?

the purpose of this is to be able to narrow the type in a collection / try / whatever. the narrow type class will flatmap whatever is inside, compare the runtime type, if it matches wrap that B in an F, or otherwise return an empty F

```
trait A
trait B extends A
object A extends A
object B extends B

val bb: List[B] = List(A, A, B, B, A)
  .narrow[B]
assert(bb == List(B, B))
```

Comment: This is now supported in Scala 3.

Comment: as of 3.0.0-RC1 - https://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2021/02/17/scala3-rc1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a polymorphic function, if you can handle the ugliness:

```scala
extension [F[_], A] (fa: F[A]):
  def narrow() = [B <: A] => (using op: Narrow[F, A, B]) => op(fa)
```

You can then call it with `foo.narrow()[String]`. [Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CRvtBO05REiluFDKW3Tqlw) it is in Scastie.

The `narrow()` is necessary, because without it, the type argument would go to the extension and not the polymorphic function.

In the future, Scala 3 may allow type arguments directly to methods inside extensions, but right now, you can keep using your Scala 2 implicit class and change it after the next release:

```
implicit class NarrowOps[F[_], A](fa: F[A]):
  def narrow[B <: A](using op: Narrow[F, A, B]) = op(fa)
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1czNkYpbR62ltLRkiLhBDw)

Side note: You don't need `B: ClassTag` again in your extension, although I believe you do need to use the bound `B <: A`.

Comment: of course i dont need to the ClassTag as its written, but once i try to implement an actual Narrow then i will need it for runtime type checking

Comment: this is a neat trick though. will put it in my toolbox for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I wasnt able to live with the `()` on the call site. I decided trying a implicit conversion to a type with an apply method with just a type parameter.

```
trait NarrowTypeClass[F[_], A, B <: A: ClassTag]:
  def apply(fa: F[A]): F[B]

given [F[_], A] as Conversion[F[A], Narrowable[F, A]] = Narrowable(_)

sealed class Narrowable [F[_], A] (fa: F[A]):
  def narrow[B <: A: ClassTag] (using op: NarrowTypeClass[F, A, B]): F[B] = op(fa)
```

this seems to do the trick